# multiple post methods in same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to create web api with multiple post actions.

I have 2 post actions

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Search")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search(string value)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpPost]  
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CreateModel app)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

and routes defined in webApiConfig file:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

/api/Controller with POST hit Post, /api/Controller/Search return 404 - not found

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having more than POST actions in the same controller and you've clearly made the distinction between them.

The problem in you case lies in how you've defined the routes. You can observe that both the Actions don't have a parameter by name 'id' but yet you're describing them in your routes.

First, remove the mention of id parameter from your route say for example

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Ideally, this should take you to POST method and in case if you add /Search in your URL it should take you to Search method.

Additionally, you can use [Web API Route Debugger Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/) to help you identify how route matching is happening and course correct the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for this.

First, in your WebApiConfig.cs, add

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Then define the route as a string in the Route attribute ontop of the methods as this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/controller/search")] 
public HttpResponseMessage Search(string value)
{
    return null;
}

[HttpPost] 
[Route("api/controller/create")] 
public HttpResponseMessage CreateModel([FromBody]CreateModel app)
{
    return null;
}
```

And also, the Search method would be more suitable to use HTTP/GET.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like route is confusing for program to understand because of following reason:

when you send POST request to /api/Controller/Search - program is confused on where to go:
1) api/{controller}/{action} as {id} is optional here
or
2) api/{controller}/{id}

Both have same route structure. So for your given example there are 2 possible way for route to redirect and that will land you on 404.

Your route must filter down to one unique path, I believe you need to change your route here.